# ¿Cómo lleno un input con un valor del localStorage al finalizar un refresh de la página?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando con esto; pero no me sale ni el alert.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        alert("Página recargada");
    });

    window.ready = function() {
        alert("Página recargada");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: window.onload = function() {
  alert("Página recargada");
};
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Diferencias 

https://www.bufa.es/jquery-document-ready-window-load/

Comment: Muchas gracias @LucianoMontañez

Answer (score 1):

Usando JQuery, introduce tu alert dentro de la función ready, tal que así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   //code
   alert("Página recargada");
})
</script>
```